# How do I find the backing store for Amasty Full Page Cache?

Tags: full-page-cache, ee-1.13

## Background

I just inherited a Magento site. The last guy left without leaving any notes/documentation. :) I know we're using AMFPC because the module is installed and enabled, and the business team has a process to flush it at certain times (and the site gets a little bit slower when they do this until the cache is warmed up).  I'm trying to figure out where the cache is actually storing data.

## Question

Is it on disk somewhere?  Or is it on a separate cache server?

## More Context

We have a cache server running memcached so I'm wondering how I can tell if AMFPC is pointed at memcached somehow.  We have 2 web servers so I'm hoping it's a distributed cache so it can be shared between both servers, but I don't know how to check.

I checked `app/etc/amfpc.xml` as well as the module in Magento Admin but couldn't find anything.

Can someone explain how to trace what is backing the AMFPC?

## Update 1

I checked folders in `MAGENTO_ROOT/var` and found the `full_page_cache` and `amasty_cache` are both empty:

```
[myuser@webserver var]$ ls
amasty_fpc  cache  full_page_cache  locks  log  report  resource_config.json  sli  tmp
[myuser@webserver var]$ du amasty_fpc/
4   amasty_fpc/
[myuser@webserver var]$ du full_page_cache/
4   full_page_cache/mage--tags
16  full_page_cache/
[myuser@webserver var]$ sudo du cache/
80  cache/mage--b
3048    cache/mage--d
256 cache/mage--7
3200    cache/mage--9
340 cache/mage--5
308 cache/mage--1
224 cache/mage--4
101584  cache/mage--f
852 cache/mage--6
552 cache/mage--2
5212    cache/mage--3
3220    cache/mage--c
236 cache/mage--8
8504    cache/mage--e
3000    cache/mage--0
200 cache/mage--a
130820  cache/
```

However, `cache` appears to be populated.  Not sure what that one does anyway.  I also checked `app/etc/local.xml` and found this:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://<IP_ADDRESS_OF_MY_CACHE_SERVER:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

That matches the IP and port of my memcached server so I think it's safe to say we are using memcached for saving session data.

I didn't find anything useful in `app/etc/enterprise.xml` or in `app/etc/amfpc.xml`.

Is there any definitive place to look to see where AMFPC is storing the cached pages?

Answer (score 0):

Congrats for inheriting a Magento site :).  I'm a big fan of Amasty's full page caching system.  It works really well, usually without any tricky configuration.

On a single server installation, the cache files are often going to be in the /var/ directory.

If you're running two front end Web servers, then it is more likely that it's in a memcached instance or reddis location that can be easily accessed by both servers.

I would check the local.xml file in the /app/etc/ directory - this is usually where the location to the reddis or memcached instance is referenced.

Quick edit: I just noticed that you're running Magento Enterprise 1.13; that has it's own full page caching system.  (Usually we wouldn't see Amasty full page cache running on an Enterprise site, as full page cache is a built-in feature of Magento Enterprise.)  There's also another xml file to check in the /app/etc/ directory that deals with full page caching as well; I think it's the enterprise.xml file, so check there.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff Finkelstein.  I'll check those locations.  I know we tried using the built-in FPC before my time, but Amasty was supposedly better when we tried so we stuck with it.

Comment: I updated the question for more details.  TY!